# Aceitar todo o tipo de dados

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

Tenho esta função em JS que aceita por exemplo 1234, mas eu quero que também aceite 12:34 (formato hora). Desconfio que o problema está no parseInt, ou seja, em vez de ser parseInt(txtValue...) passa a ser parseString(), so que me esta a faltar algo. :S

```
function BtnSaveParametrizacaoTempos_Validate() {
  var erro = 0;
  var txtValueObj = $("#<%=txtValue.TextBoxClientID%>");            

  if (txtValueObj.val().trim() === ("" + parseInt(txtValueObj.val(), 10))) { 

    ITCore.Presentation.InsertValidateMsg($("#<%= txtValue.TextBoxClientID%>"), ""); 
    erro = 0; 

  } else { 

    ITCore.Presentation.InsertValidateMsg(
      $("#<%= txtValue.TextBoxClientID%>"), 
      "<%=ITCore.Common.Resources.Translate.GetTransactionString("ParametrizacaoTempos", "InvalidValue")%>"
    ); 

    erro = 1; 
  }

  ResizeIFrame();
  return erro === 0;

}
```

Pelo que estive a ver na bd ele está com um campo que é isNumeric e tá a NULL, logo terei de dizer na bd se for numeric faz uma coisa caso não seja faz outra, certo?

Comment: Podes dar exemplos de valores que deve aceitar e valores que não deve aceitar?

Comment: O que deveria acontecer quando a entrada é "12:34"? Descreva melhor seu problema e qual a solução pretendida, assim como o Sergio comentou. O que você quer dizer com "todo tipo de dado"?

Comment: certo! neste Caso posso aceitar valores presentes numa string, exemplo: "12234", "qwer", "12:23", "1s2dsa". Quando coloco por exemplo 12:34 ele diz valor inválido, por so aceita o seguinta "1234", "abcd" e "a1cd23" e não pode ser null!!

Comment: Então basicamente ela só não pode ser nula?

Comment: o que seu codigo hoje faz é verificar se foi digitado um numero inteiro (que é o mesmo tipo de dado que seu bd espera, correto?) se voce vai passar a aceitar qualquer tipo de dado no campo agora, voce vai ter que mudar o campo do seu bd pra aceitar qualquer valor

Comment: A bd aceita qualquer tipo de dados! Está como varchar(500)! O problema esta mesmo nesta função que nao deixa introduzir qualquer tipo de dados.